# XSL replace two types of characters in string values

Tags: java, regex, xml, xslt

So let's say we have two scenarios where the XML may either contain birthdays with characters `/` or `-`. Example: `1966-02-02` or `1977/03/04`.

I would like to remove those characters, so that the value becomes `19660202` and `19770304`, respectively

Now, my current xsl looks like this:

```
<xsl:if test="$person/birthDate != '' ">
  <xsl:attribute name="birthday">                                        
    <xsl:variable name="dob" select="$person/birthDate"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($dob)>10">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($dob,1,10)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$dob"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>   
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

How do I go about removing those characters in those two scenarios?

Comment: Please... take a few seconds to layout your code in a readable way, why all the indentation to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do just want to remove `/` or `-` then you don't need to regular expressions, you can just use the [`translate` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) to remove them

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($dob, '/-', '')"/>
```

Or, to save doing this in two places, you could use it in the variable statement, like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="dob" select="translate($person/birthDate, '/-', '')"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($dob)>8"><xsl:value-of select="substring($dob,1,8)"/></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$dob"/></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

If you really did want to use regular expressions, you could code it like this instead:

```
<xsl:variable name="dob" select="replace($person/birthDate, '/|-', '')"/>
```

using the [`replace` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-replace).

Comment: The `replace` function will only work if the OP uses XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, the `translate` solution will work with anyone version of XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use a double translate function

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($dob, translate($dob, '0123456789', ''), '')"/>
```

this will extract only the numbers in the string